# asp.net gridview pager hover

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

when i hover over my gridview, i apply css to highlight the row the mouse is over. this gets applied to the pager aswell though which is located on the top and bottom of my gridview. can i **not** apply the color style css to the pager row?
thanks
Damo

**CSS**

```
.mGrid tr:hover{background-color:#FFFFCC;color:white;}
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewMain" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewMain_PageIndexChanging"
     runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom"
     CssClass="mGrid"
     PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
     AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
     OnRowCreated="GridViewMain_RowCreated">
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind to add a dropdown to the pager**

```
protected void GridViewMain_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
            {
                DropDownList GridViewMainddl = new DropDownList();
                //adds variants of pager size
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("5");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("10");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("20");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("50");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("100");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("200");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("500");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("All");
                GridViewMainddl.AutoPostBack = true;
                //selects item due to the GridView current page size
                ListItem li = GridViewMainddl.Items.FindByText(GridViewMain.PageSize.ToString());
                if (li != null)
                    GridViewMainddl.SelectedIndex = GridViewMainddl.Items.IndexOf(li);
                GridViewMainddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(GridViewMainddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
                //adds dropdownlist in the additional cell to the pager table
                Table pagerTable = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as Table;
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Style["padding-left"] = "15px";
                cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Page Size:"));
                cell.Controls.Add(GridViewMainddl);
                pagerTable.Rows[0].Cells.Add(cell);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `RowStyle-CssClass` property of `GridView` to apply a class to just the data rows in your grid.  Then use that class in you stylesheet to apply the hover styles.

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewMain"
    OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewMain_PageIndexChanging"
    runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True"
    PageSize="5"
    PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom"
    CssClass="mGrid"
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt data-row"
    RowStyle-CssClass="data-row"
    OnRowCreated="GridViewMain_RowCreated">
 </asp:GridView>
```

Style:

`.mGrid tr.data-row:hover { background-color:#FFFFCC; color:white; }`

Comment: hi, this works but then on each row of the actual grid only every second row gets the color when the mouse is moved over it

Comment: Then add the `data-row` class to the `AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass`.  Would be like this: `AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt data-row"`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: you are a genius! my fault BTW to evertone for not including this detail in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Row_DataBound event of your gridview.. You can select only the cellls that contain data and not include the Pager in that.. Try this

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFCC'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use the inline styles.. then you can use ClassNames as well .. But you need to add a bit of jQuery code into you page.. 
In the head section of your page just include this and it should work fine as well..

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
   .hoverClass
   {
       background-color: Red !important;
       color: Green !important;
   }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(PostBack);
       PostBack();
   });

   function PostBack() {
      $('tbody tr:gt(1)').mouseover(function() {
           $(this).addClass('hoverClass');
       }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hoverClass');
       });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: hi, this does work perfect, however ideally i would like to use CSS only as it makes the project more extensible as i have many grids that this style will be applied to and i have unfortunately a few row_databound events for various grids. this is an excellent answer if CSS will not do the trick......

Comment: I have added some code if you want to use Class Names instead of inline styles

Comment: thanks a million. the css marked as the answer is the way i will implement this feature. thanks you for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this..

```
.mGrid tr:not(.pgr):hover{background-color:#FFFFCC;color:white;}
```

Comment: hi, this works but i also have a page size dropdown that still gets the alternate color. ive added the code above that does this

Comment: You may try this instead of above the above one. `.mGrid tr:not(.pgr):hover, .mGrid tr:not(.pgr):not(select):hover{background-color:#FFFFCC;color:white;}`